# What is "Summary of Tikz commands" about?

Tags: discussion

There is [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84753/summary-of-tikz-commands) on Tex.SE asking about a "Summary of Tikz commands".

I added somethings I thought were relevant [revision 10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/84757/revisions). But @percusse thought "that's not what this answer is about." and reversed my editing. Unfortunately  he has not answer my question of what is this answer about, then?/Why not this?

Answer (score 2):

What you did is expanding command to how it can be used but that is already in the `<path specification part>`. We discussed this when the answer was shaping back then. See the **Path Specification** section of the answer for your addition given in a more detailed fashion.